# Bad Address Data

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssis

I am working on a project where I get information from an outside vender in an Excel report and I need to process it through a series of transformations but the below data needs to be split out so that I can have the City and State and dump the rest of the data.

Here is an example of the bad data
[PlantName]

```
|ATLANTA,GA AIRPORT ONSITE|
|BETHLEHEM, PA|
|ANCHORAGE, AK No Ship  HazMat|
|FOREST PARK, GA|
|HUNTINGTON,WV No Ship|
```

Here is an example of the clean data I need

[PlantName], [City], [State]

```
|ATLANTA|ATLANTA|GA|
|BETHLEHEM|BETHLEHEM|PA|
|ANCHORAGE|ANCHORAGE|AK|
|FOREST PARK|FOREST PARK|GA|
|HUNTINGTON|HUNTINGTON|WV|
```

I will need to have the City Name in the Plant Name so that I can use it in a naming convention, a concatenation with another field to create an actual plant name.

I want to use an SSIS expression but I am open to T-SQL if it is quicker and more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I used a series of Derived Columns to separate the Data followed up by a Derived Column with a Token Expression to pull the State Abbrev out of the final row and disregard any useless characters.